# How to output date value from a text

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, text

So I have obfuscated date information in my column. e.g. Jan preplan-2017, Feb-afterplan-2017-low, etc.

Two things are always consistent: Months always come in the beginning with 3 letters. And year comes in 4 digits (may in anywhere.)

I basically need them in the standard date format( e.g. 1/1/2017, 1/2/2017, etc.)

Comment: This is not a standard date form - are you asking to do `m.d.yyyy` or `d.m.yyyy`?

Comment: Also, side question, but why are you storing your data like that to begin with?  It's very counter-productive.  If you store your `date` values as an actual `date` datatype, you wouldn't be having this issue.

Comment: `I basically need them in the standard date form: 1.1.2017, 1.2.2017` <= no, that is also a bad idea, *almost as bad as the idea to store them in that format to begin with*. You should store and retrieve them as actual `date` or `datetime` types. There is a good reason there is a type system to begin with, otherwise everything would just be a string. A date is a date, not a string.

Comment: here you go: [standard date form](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: Why did you "obfuscated" your data in the firts place?

Comment: @Siyual d.m.yyyy is the format I wanted. And yes, I want to convert the data from text format to a date format.

Comment: @Igor  That is exactly what I want. But the input data I receive has unnecessary text info, which I need to get rid of in order to do that.

Comment: @JoshPart I didn't obfuscate the data. It comes in that form.

Answer (score 1):

First convert your string to a date value:

```
s = "Jan preplan-2017"
TrueDate = DateValue("1 " & Left(s, 3) & " " & Right(s, 4))
```

Then - for display - format as required:

```
ShowDate = Format(TrueDate, "d.m.yyyy")
```

Or in one go:

```
ShowDate = Format(DateValue("1 " & Left(s, 3) & " " & Right(s, 4)), "d.m.yyyy")
```

Edit: Use Split to create an array of the elements, loop these and pick the one that is an integer:

```
Year = Split("Feb-afterplan-2017-low", "-")(2)
```

Comment: Left() works perfect! But the problem with Right() is  that the year may come in the middle as well. If I could filter our non-numeric that would work

Comment: Oh, then you will have to strip it somehow. Does it always come with a leading or trailing dash: `"-"` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not brilliant with RegEx so no doubt this can be improved.

As a worksheet function:

```
Public Function ConvertDate(sData As String) As Variant
    Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object
    Dim Temp As String

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\d{4}"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(sData)
    If REMatches.Count > 0 Then
        Temp = "1-" & Left(sData, 3) & "-" & REMatches(0)
        ConvertDate = CDate(DateValue(Temp))
    Else
        'Returns #VALUE error on no match.
        ConvertDate = CVErr(xlValue)
    End If
End Function
```

Passes date by reference and returns TRUE/FALSE:

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim MyDate As Date

    If ConvertDate1("Jan preplan-2017", MyDate) Then
        MsgBox "Date converted to " & Format(MyDate, "dd-mmm-yy"), vbOKOnly
    Else
        MsgBox "Date not converted.", vbOKOnly
    End If

End Sub

Public Function ConvertDate1(sData As String, ByRef ReturnValue As Date) As Boolean
    Dim RE As Object, REMatches As Object
    Dim Temp As String

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\d{4}"
    End With

    Set REMatches = RE.Execute(sData)
    If REMatches.Count > 0 Then
        Temp = "1-" & Left(sData, 3) & "-" & REMatches(0)
        ReturnValue = CDate(DateValue(Temp))
        ConvertDate1 = True
    Else
        ConvertDate1 = False
    End If
End Function
```

The RegEx can be improved to check first three letters are a month... loads can be done to improve, but you get the picture I hope.